# Attach timestamp to each line of stdout

Tags: linux, bash, logging

Im am hosting some game servers, and each server instance runs in stdout, but they don't have timestamps, just logging events to new lines, e.g.:

- player a connected
- player b connected
- game started
- player X fragged player Y
- game ended

etc.

The problem with this is that when the server crashes I have no idea when did that happen.

Is there a way to pipe servers stdout trough some command, and get the same output back to file, or stdout again, but with timestamp in front???

Comment: The moreutils `ts` (timestamp) command does exactly this, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49808543/6272277 / https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/

Answer (score 3):

Create a bash script as the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
        timestamp=`date`
        echo "[$timestamp] $line"
done
```

Call it `relog.sh` and set it as executable issuing `chmod +x relog.sh`
Then you can pipe through it and it will print a timestamp followed by the original log line. For example, issuing `cat /etc/services | ./relog.sh` will produce an output similar to this:

```
[Wed Oct 28 22:34:25 CET 2015] netmap_lm       1493/tcp                # netmap_lm
[Wed Oct 28 22:34:25 CET 2015] netmap_lm       1493/udp                # netmap_lm
[Wed Oct 28 22:34:25 CET 2015] cvc             1495/tcp                # cvc
[Wed Oct 28 22:34:25 CET 2015] cvc             1495/udp                # cvc
```

Please note that the above script is only a stub; you can (must?) complete it as per your needs.

Answer (score 1):

This could be **much faster** than a bash script but basically does the same thing.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Print each line of stdin
while() {
        # Grab the current time
        my @now = localtime();

        # Rearrange the following to suit your stamping needs.
        # it currently generates YYYYMMDDhhmmss
        my $timeStamp = sprintf("%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d",
                        $now[5]+1900, $now[4]+1, $now[3],
                        $now[2],      $now[1],   $now[0]);

        print ($timeStamp, " $_");
}
```

Execute as

> yourapp | thisscript.pl

Example

```
$ ./a | ./stdout.pl 
20151028200508 test
20151028200509 test2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ts` command from moreutils (apt get moreutils).

```
 $ ls -1 | ts

Oct 12 20:09:27 ts-out.v37mPS
Oct 12 20:09:27 ts-out.vavMYs
Oct 12 20:09:27 ts-out.wd9G1Y
Oct 12 20:09:27 ts-out.ym8aN0
Oct 12 20:09:27 ts-out.zCzWhY
```